# How can I split up a PDF file into pages (preferably C#)

Tags: c#, pdf

My client has a multi-page PDF file.  They need it split by page.  Does anyone know of a way to do this - preferably in C#.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.com/) is an open source library which may be what you're after:

> Key Features
>
> - Creates PDF documents on the fly from any .Net language
> - Easy to understand object model to compose documents
> - One source code for drawing on a PDF page as well as in a window or on the printer
> - Modify, merge, and split existing PDF files

[This sample](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=37&Itemid=48) shows how to convert a PDF document with n pages into n documents with one page each.

Answer (score 4):

I did this using [ITextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net) -- there are commercial options that may have a good API but this is open source and free, and not hard to use.

Check out [this code](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/examples/Split.cs), it's one of their code samples -- it's pretty good.  It splits a PDF file into two files at the passed-in page number.  You can modify it to loop and split page by page.

Comment: iTextSharp is no more free to use in commerical applications. It is currently released under AGPL license. Ghostscript can split a pdf.           "gs -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=page{page:04d}.pdf"
              " -dFirstPage={page} -dLastPage={page}"
              " -sDEVICE=pdfwrite {input_pdf}"

Answer (score 2):

Haven't played with it, but you can look at [Aspose.Pdf.Kit for .NET and Java](http://www.aspose.com/categories/file-format-components/aspose.pdf.kit-for-.net-and-java/default.aspx). It is commercial so you'll need to pay licensing feeds, but if you need commercial support it might work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Siberix offers a reasonably costed commercial library for creating PDF's on the fly in .NET: http://siberix.com  You can create the PDF's programmatically or through an XML transformation (and a combination of both IIRC).

I've used their library on a couple of projects and have found that not only is their library easy to work with, but their email support is incredible.  And the license is quite cheap as well.